# How to access the published field in my PHP code?

Tags: 7

I am defining a datatype called slider

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'slider'));
foreach($nodes as $slider):
```

and trying to iterate through each of them. I want to access the field which says if the content is publised or not. I tried this -

```
$slider->$status == 1
```

But this is not working.
Does anyone have a solution this problem?

Thanks

Comment: How php works isn't really on topic for this site. Perhaps the question could be moved to stack overflow?

Comment: As @Letharion, this is a PHP question. Drupal doesn't change the PHP syntax to allow `$object->$property`.

Answer (score 1):

It is

```
$slider->status == 1
```

instead of

```
$slider->$status == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) to get al `nid`s

```
 $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
 $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'mycontenttype')
    ->execute();
 $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
 foreach($nodes as $node){
  if($node->status == 1)
  drupal_set_message('node '.$node->title.' is Active');
 }
```